# Change Sitename/Applicationname causes MsBuild failure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, tfs, iis-7, msbuild

I am using MVC3 application,and am creating packages through TFS build.it was working fine when i am creating Packages through MSBuild.

Previously Website1 has my application(Website1/Application) in IIS,now i want to relocate my Application under Website2,like(Website2/Application),in the Package/PublishWeb properties.

But my TFS(MSBuild) Build was failed with following error

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets
>   (3847): Web deployment task failed. (Site 'Website2' does not exist.).

do i need to change may Sitename any other place? Please help us to fixing this issue.

My configuration

```
             <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
<DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
<Optimize>true</Optimize>
<OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>AllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
<DeployOnBuild>true</DeployOnBuild>
<DeployTarget>MsDeployPublish</DeployTarget>
<MSDeployPublishMethod>InProc</MSDeployPublishMethod>
<CreatePackageOnPublish>true</CreatePackageOnPublish>
<MsDeployServiceURL>localhost</MsDeployServiceURL>
<DeployIisAppPath>Analytics/Application</DeployIisAppPath>
      </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Can you show us more of your configuration settings? Where have you defined your website name? How are you creating your package? Just running MSBuild with a deploy option or .. ?

Comment: added my configuration above.i am creating packages creating a build definition.

Comment: The error suggests you do not have a Website2 defined in IIS. Have you created one?

Comment: @ KevDevMan,please let me know where i should create this website.in local we don't have iis.